# problem updating simulator_gazebo1.7.6 in a overlay

Tags: gazebo, simulation, simulator-gazebo, update, overlay

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, i'm trying to update my simulator gazebo to fix the contact sensors problem, i'am working with ubuntu 12.04 and ROS fuerte, i'm following the [Overlay_intallation](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Overlays), but when i try to update the repository i obtain this:

```
jose@ubuntu:~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox$ rosws set simulator_gazebo --hg https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/tags/simulator_gazebo-1.7.6/simulator_gazebo

     Add new elements:
  sandbox/simulator_gazebo      hg  https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/tags/simulator_gazebo-1.7.6/simulator_gazebo   

Continue: (y)es, (n)o: y
Overwriting /home/jose/fuerte_workspace/.rosinstall

Do not forget to do ...
$ source /home/jose/fuerte_workspace/setup.sh
... in every open terminal.
Config changed, remember to run 'rosws update sandbox/simulator_gazebo' to update the folder from hg
jose@ubuntu:~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox$ rosws update simulator_gazebo
[sandbox/simulator_gazebo] Installing https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/tags/simulator_gazebo-1.7.6/simulator_gazebo (version None) to /home/jose/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/simulator_gazebo
abort: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
Exception caught during install: Error processing 'sandbox/simulator_gazebo' : [sandbox/simulator_gazebo] Checkout of https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/tags/simulator_gazebo-1.7.6/simulator_gazebo version None into /home/jose/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/simulator_gazebo failed.

ERROR: Error processing 'sandbox/simulator_gazebo' : [sandbox/simulator_gazebo] Checkout of https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/tags/simulator_gazebo-1.7.6/simulator_gazebo version None into /home/jose/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/simulator_gazebo failed.
```

Anyone could help me???

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49389/problem-updating-simulator_gazebo1.7.6-in-a-overlay/) by [joseescobar60](https://answers.ros.org/users/3496/joseescobar60/) on ROS Answers with karma: 172 on 2012-11-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There were some server issues in the last few days.  The 404 errors suggests that the files it was looking for were unavailable.  I'd suggest trying again.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0